# Where can I ask questions about email campaigns?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am trying to figure out where is the best place to post a question regarding email campaigns and configuration with Google.

I just started working for a yoga studio and noticed that all their Mail Chimp emails go straight to my "Promotions" folder on gmail. There are 1,500 people on the mailing list and I am trying to see if there is a way to avoid being sent to the Promotions folder (presumably the junk/spam folder on other platforms).

I was thinking Super User but am unsure.

Answer (score 6):

[Pro Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) is likely your best option.  They have a [mailchimp](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mailchimp) tag that would be relevant, and there are a decent number of [posts related to delivering mail to Gmail](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=gmail%20closed%3A0) as well.

Their [on-topic page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) also lists "Internet marketing" as one of the primary categories of questions accepted there.

I believe this would be off-topic on WebApps.SE, because while [questions about SaaS email fulfillment providers are on-topic there](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2339/254174), they must be about *using* the application, which this is not.  It is similarly not about *using* Gmail: it's about delivering mail to Gmail.

Comment: As a personal side note, if this _is_ a promotion/marketing campaign, then Gmail is doing what it's supposed to :-)

Answer (score 3):

You might be better off with [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/). Their [on-topic guidance](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) covers...

> Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which **behaves like an application**

Which sounds about right for your question. Additionally, they have an active [gmail tag](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail), and there are already a few questions regarding Gmail folders, like [this one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/84110/251278) I found with a [simple search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgmail%5D+promotion).

Comment: This question doesn't really seem to be "about the Gmail service as accessed by a desktop or mobile browser," as described in that tag guidance, but rather delivering mail to Gmail users as part of a campaign.

Comment: So it seems. Pro Webmasters appears to be a better choice. Nice answer @RyanM :)